# Javascript - Remove leading zero from string

Tags: javascript, rounding, strip

This is probably a super easy one. But I've got a series of numbers which looks like this:

```
0.12704174228675136
0.3629764065335753
```

I want to remove the leading `0.` and keep only the two first numbers, so this is the result:

```
12
36
```

But I don't know how to round numbers . Usually, I'd convert it to a string and use regular expression. I guess I could do that now as well, but since I've got numbers here, I mind as well learn this now.

Comment: So is it integer or string? First you mentioned 'integer strings' next time only 'integer'? so what now?

Comment: It's only integers, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they're already strings, `substr`'ll do the trick:

```
str.substr(2, 2);
```

If they're numbers, you can multiply and use `Math.floor`:

```
Math.floor(number * 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and easiest way:

```
number*100|0;
```

(`|` is bit wise OR and it will convert any number to an integer, thus behaving the same as `Math.floor` but shorter and faster.)

Answer (score 1):

a couple of ways to do this

```
Math.floor(number*100);
```

Probably the most correct as you are working with a number the whole time.

```
parseInt(number*100, 10);
```

parseInt is supposed to take a string as first argument, but if you pass it a number javascript will convert to string.

```
(number+"").replace(/\d*\.(\d{2})\d*/, "$1");
```

Or convert to string and regex

Comment: Eek!  parseInt does NOT convert to string (not in Firefox 38, anyway).  And using it without a radix is scary because it might assume octal.

Comment: yeah, I guess I wasn't clear that it's not the function that does the conversion.  It's javascript's crazy type coercion.  Good point on using the radix.